# "People widget" has disappeared in Gmail

Tags: gmail, widgets

Since a week or two ago, the "People widget" has disappeared in Gmail in my desktop browser. This is the widget that appears on the right-hand side of all emails, that shows information on the people participating in that email chain.

I already have "Show the people widget" enabled, as I always have.

Perhaps this coincides with the recent launch of [Gmail addons](https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/do-more-your-inbox-gmail-add-ons/)?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that it is because of Google's update.

More concretely, after the launch of Gmail Add-ons (Oct 24, 2017), the right-hand-side of Gmail has been removed.

People widget has been very important and good feature for me until now.

I really hope Google will revive this feature. Please...

Answer (score -1):

This is really annoying, not because I think the widget was particularly useful for my type of work, but because the message column is just too damn wide now!

A possible workaround is enabling a Labs option that moves the Hangouts chat to the right side, but I don't like it, for aesthetic reasons.